# How to gather a dataset of labeled resumes for training ML models

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am building an algorithm for classifying resumes using CNN. I have found pretty cool concepts but I can't test them because I can't find a labeled database of resumes.

Is there a legal, and free way to obtain such dataset ?

Comment: For the record, you should always think about how to get training data *before* building a model. Otherwise it's like building a swimming pool without having access to any water ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can browse through Kaggle to see if there is any that will match what you need, but here is one that could be useful gotten from Kaggle.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gauravduttakiit/resume-dataset

Comment: I have this dataset but it's a little bit short, but thank you! Do you have any other website I can browse ?

Comment: Check out this one, this was collected by web scraping as it contains some html tags, haven't opened yet, maybe it can be helpful.

Here is the link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/snehaanbhawal/resume-dataset